# Javascript html append

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say i have the following function:

```
    generateHtml() {
        let returnhtml;
        returnhtml = html `<div>
           <h2>${this.data.title}</h2>
</div>`;
        this.data.columnData.map(column => {
            switch (column.dataType) {
                case 'image':
                    returnhtml += html `<div><img src=${column.imageSrc}></div>`;
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    returnhtml += html `<div><p>${column.text}</p></div>`;
                    break;
            }
        });
        return returnhtml;
    }
```

Now when i run this the `returnhtml` at the end is:

```
"[object Object][object Object][object Object]"
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: "returnhtml += html `<div>HTML code</div>`;" - this is not a string, you are calling `html` function with value from literal. I don't know what `html` stands for here, but it probably would work with returnhtml += `<div><img src=${column.imageSrc}></div>`;

Answer (score 0):

We can't see you `html` function, but without it (and with small correction) you is worked:

```
const generateHtml = () => {
        let returnhtml = `<div><h2>${data.title}</h2></div>`
        data.columnData.map(column => {
            switch (column.dataType) {
                case 'image':
                    returnhtml += `<div><img src=${column.imageSrc}></div>`
                    break
                case 'text':
                    returnhtml += `<div><p>${column.text}</p></div>`
                    break
            }
        })
        return returnhtml
    }
```

See in playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s519464